# Why I am Facing conflict while using Column inside Row widget for creating a layout in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Facing conflicts while using Column widget in Row.

Hi, I am implementing below mentioned design in flutter but something went wrong mentioned in below image.

I don't want to use any external package for learning purpose. Thanks for your help in advance.

Expectations:-
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsTM4.png)

Reality:-
[Messed up layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZknL.png)

below are the code snippet, which I am using now.

**upload_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StepProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const StepProgressBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Row(
      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
      StepWithPlaceHolder(label: "1", title: "Choose File"),
      Expanded(child: Divider(thickness: 7,height: 5,)),
      StepWithPlaceHolder(label: "2", title: "Finish")
    ]);
  }
}

class StepWithPlaceHolder extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final String title;

  const StepWithPlaceHolder(
      {Key? key, required this.label, required this.title})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 55,
          height: 55,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 2, style: BorderStyle.none),
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              label,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          title,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
}
```

Comment: what happens if `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center`?

Comment: It puts divider in the center of the screen.

Comment: ```Row``` is taking full screen . Wrap ```Row``` by ```Column```

Comment: try changing `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` and `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` based on the way on your expected design It should be in the middle in the row

Comment: By adding column it comes close to what is expected, but is there any way we can make Divider close to both nodes (kind of touch to each other)?

Comment: mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, makes divider in the center of the screen.

Comment: Wrap the divider with a Padding widget and try adjusting the Vertical padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to make it dynamic so you will just need to change list in order to manage your views and here is code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StepProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const StepProgressBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final list = const [{"label":"1","title":"Choose File"},{"label":"2","title":"Finish"}];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widgets = <Widget>[];
    var textWidgets = <Widget>[];
    for(int counter=0;counter<list.length;counter++){
      var item = list[counter];
      if(counter != 0){
        textWidgets.add(Text(
          item["title"] ?? "",
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ));
        widgets.add(
              Expanded(child: Divider(thickness: 7,height: 5,)),
        );
        widgets.add(StepWithPlaceHolder(label: item["label"] ?? "",));
      }else{
        textWidgets.add(Text(
          item["title"] ?? "",
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ));
        widgets.add(StepWithPlaceHolder(label: item["label"] ?? "", ));
      }
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: widgets
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: textWidgets,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StepWithPlaceHolder extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;

  const StepWithPlaceHolder(
      {Key? key, required this.label})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 55,
          height: 55,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 2, style: BorderStyle.none),
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              label,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Code is not much optimized but you can refer it

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Row` widget with `SizedBox` with the needed height.

```
SizedBox(
    height: 80,
    child: const Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
           children: [
           //....
           Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, bottom: 10), // for padding around Divider
                child:Divider(
                      thickness: 7,
                      height: 5,
                        ),
            ),
           // ....
           ],
        ),
    ),
```

OUTPUT:

[image: See Output]

***Note:*** Or wrap With a `Container` instead of `SizedBox` if you want to add some margin around it.